# scanForPeripheralWithServices does not return anything

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am new to swift language. I have been working on establishing a bluetooth connection between my iOS app and a barcode scanner. The barcode scanner has bluetooth enabled. I tried to establish a global bluetooth connection with my iphone and it works. Based on some references from the Internet, I have written the following sample code.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

var manager : CBCentralManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager = CBCentralManager(delegate : self, queue : nil)

}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {

    var consoleMsg = "hello"

    switch(central.state) {

    case .PoweredOff:
        consoleMsg = "Bluetooth is powered off"

    case .PoweredOn:
        consoleMsg = "Bluetooth is powered on"
        manager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)

    case .Resetting:
        consoleMsg = "Bluetooth is Resetting"

    case .Unauthorized:
        consoleMsg = "Bluetooth is Unauthorized"

    case .Unknown:
        consoleMsg = "Bluetooth is Unknown"            

    case .Unsupported:
        consoleMsg = "Bluetooth is Unsupported"

    }

    print("\(consoleMsg)")
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {

    print("Discovered a peripheral \(peripheral)")
}
```

When I try to run the above code, log displays "Bluetooth is Powered on" and thats it. It is not discovering my barcode scanner. I also made sure that the barcode scanner is in discoverable mode. Why my code is not discovering the near-by bluetooth enabled barcode scanner? Have I done any mistake in the above code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely check authorization first !